# How does には work in 10年は待つには長い時間だ, following a verb?

Tags: usage

> 10年は待つには長い時間だ

In what situation can には follow a verb like in the above sentence and what is the function of it here?

Comment: Related: [The difference between するには and する為には](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29291/5010)

Answer (score 1):

> １０年は待つ**には**長い時間だ

「には」is the short form of 「にしては」in the sentence.
The sentence could have two meanings, though the first one is more natural;

1. 待｛ま｝つという単調｛たんちょう｝な行為｛こうい｝は１日や２日なら我慢｛がまん｝できるが、１０年もの長｛なが｝い期間｛きかん｝は待｛ま｝ちきれない。【例】5光年｛こうねん｝離｛はな｝れた星｛ほし｝へ行｛い｝って帰｛かえ｝る**宇宙旅行｛うちゅうりょこう｝なら飛行時間｛ひこうじかん｝として**１０年は妥当｛だとう｝だが、地球上｛ちきゅうじょう｝で帰り｛かえ｝を**待｛まつ｝には**長い時間だ。
2. 待｛ま｝たなければいけないことは承知｛しょうち｝していたが、私｛わたし｝はもう少｛すこ｝し短｛みじか｝い期間｛きかん｝だと想定｛そうてい｝していた。しかし、「10年間｛ねんかん｝待｛ま｝ってください」と言｛い｝われて、長｛なが｝過｛す｝ぎると感｛かん｝じた。【例】「借金｛しゃっきん｝は必｛かなら｝ず返｛かえ｝します。10年間｛ねんかん｝待｛ま｝ってください。」「駄目｛だめ｝だ。待｛ま｝つのは構｛かま｝わないが１年が相場｛そうば｝だろう。１０年は待｛ま｝つには長｛なが｝い時間｛じかん｝だ（長｛なが｝過｛す｝ぎる時間｛じかん｝だ）。」